# Collection View and String type help in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am trying to send pictures to a collection view, similar to the way you would do in a to do list tutorial, but I am working with images, not text. I get an error in the code where I say:

```
Picture.append(picture.image)
```

The error says that [String] does not have a member named 'image'.

How should I approach this if I cant use a string? What other type should I use?

I am also getting an error in the cellForItemAtIndexPath section. This is my code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell
    cell.ImageView.image = UIImage(named: picture[indexPath.row])
    return cell

}
```

In this I am getting an error that saying as Cell at the end of the first line is undeclared, but I am not sure where or how I am supposed to declare this, since I have other projects with Collection Views and I didn't need to declare anything.

Please let me know if you can help, Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some of the code where you are initializing picture? From the code posted here it's hard to tell what that var really contains—image data?  Really, that's true for "Picture" too. The error seems to indicate that it is an Array of Strings. Are those strings the paths of the images?

Comment: You are correct, I am dealing with Image data being passed from an ImageView to a collection view. So yes, the strings are the paths of the images. How should I fix this? And what code do you want me to add? The collection view class or sending data to collection class? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe I see the source of the errors.  I'll cover each error below, and suggestions on how to alleviate them.

---

```
Picture.append(picture.image)
```

> Error:  [String] does not have a member named 'image'.

Since you are acquiring the member "image" via dot-notation from the object "picture", that error suggests that "picture" (the lowercase one) is an array of standard Swift Strings.

Swift Strings do not have a property named "image" in them, so the error is pointing that out.  If you just want the filename for your images, it can be left as a String.

Then, when you call it in your next Snippet of code, it just pulls out the filename String and passes it to that UIImage initializer.

From looking at your code in the next snippet, I think you might actually have meant something like this:

```
let image = "someImage.png"  //The filename for the image to append to the array.
var picture = [String]()     //An array of Strings to hold the filenames to the images.

picture.append(image)
```

In this case we have an array called "picture", and then we append the filename String (stored as the String named "image") to this array.

---

```
var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell
```

> Error:  Use of undeclared type 'Cell'

This says that the Cell type is undeclared.  I have not used UICollectionView yet, but from my understanding, its data type is a UICollectionViewCell, not just "Cell" (the capital one).  You would probably have to type that as a UICollectionViewCell.

From my research, it appears that a UICollectionViewCell does not have a member named `ImageView`.  In that case, you could write a custom subclass of UICollectionViewCell named Cell, and give it a property named ImageView, like:

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell
{
    var imageView = UIImageView()
}

cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "someImage.png")
```

One note about my code above, I renamed the property to "imageView" (now starting with lowercase 'I').  Apple suggests that we name only Types (like UICollectionViewCell or String) with capital letters at the beginning.  Functions and properties should start with lowercase letters to conform to that coding standard.

Then you can wire your imageView from the storyboard or other part of code to this property, and set your UICollectionViewCell to this "Cell" type, and set the imageView property.

---

For more information on using UICollectionViews, take at look at [Brian J Coleman's post "Tutorial: Collection View Using Swift"](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-collection-view-using-swift/)

I hope my answer has been of help.  Good luck on learning Swift!

Comment: When I add let image = imageView.image above the append line,I get a different error that says, "Cannot convert the expression's type 'UIImage?' to type 'String -> ()'" I already have the string picture declared as well... Do you know why this would be showing up now?

Comment: @gskril The type of imageView.image is a `UIImage?`.  The type of the array is `String`.  When you call imageView.image, you are setting the new image constant to be a `UIImage?`.  Thus when you try to append it, the error says that it cannot convert that UIImage?.  I am a little confused by the `String -> (), which is more of a closure, but it might be referring to the append being a String based function for this array.

Comment: So how do you suggest I fix this? Change the type of string or something? Not really sure what to do

Comment: The array either needs to hold only filename Strings, or UIImages.  Your previous comment was trying to read a UIImage back into the String array.  There are two choices.  First, have a String array that you load with filenames, and then construct their UIImages in your cellForRowAtIndexPath (like your question's cellForRowAtIndexPath does.  Second, you can actually load an array of UIImages, and then just assign them directly to the imageView.image for the cell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath.  The first way only load what will be needed.  The second way has higher initial loadtime.

Comment: Way 1 is what I was trying to do originally... I am just getting those error that I posted in the original question. Then once I added the let statement line, i got the error posted in my first comment. As of now, I am running the app by deleting the code where I am getting the errors, but now its obviusly not sending the photo to the collection View. Would you be able to look deeper into the problems if I post more code? Thanks for all this by the way, and sorry for the questions